# DS-160 - I am a recent medical graduate (completed in September 2021), what can I write in primary occupation?

Tags: visas, usa

My question is I am a recent medical graduate from EU (completed in September 2021), what can I write in primary occupation in DS-160?  I am yet to get my license.

Comment: what is a DS-160 ?

Comment: @Max Application for US non-immigrant visa

Comment: Are you currently employed or under contract to start?

Comment: Why do you think it is not “physician”?

Comment: @Damila The real question is why you think it would be. Judging by the question OP is not currently a physician, never has been in the past, and doesn't yet have the license required to act as one.

Comment: @Damila, there is no option of physician....even if the option was there, one can't select that as the license is required.

Answer (score 3):

The ['exemplar' (sample) DS-160 form](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/PDF-other/DS-160-Example_11-19-2020.pdf) (pdf) says "Primary Occupation". The follow-up question is "present employer or school name." If you aren't currently enrolled in school and aren't working, I think you must put unemployed or not enrolled.

Comment: Or possibly choose ‘Other’ and provide the explanation given in the OP’s question.